# How do I make character play another animation when moving left?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have script which makes character (gameobject) move right.

How do I make so when he reaches right border, and character starts moving left with playing another animation (moving left)?

Here is my script of character's moving right and left

```
void MovementRight()
{
    _character.transform.Translate (Vector2.right 100f Time.deltaTime);
}

void MovementLeft()
{
    _character.transform.Translate (Vector3.left 100f Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you handle animations with Animator, and make the horizontal animation to be handled by a float variable in Animator, (so when it is -1 animate walking left, and 1 animate walking right).

So you will need to make 3 scripts.
//This will handle the animator getting the speed of the character from MovingHandler
AnimationHandler.cs

//This will actually move the character based on input handler
MovingHandler.cs

//Here you will hear to inputs
InputHandler.cs

And to make suere the character won't move outside the screen you will need to get the screenbounds on MovingHandler and make a check before moving the character, if it is in the same spot in x as the bounds of the screen you will make a return; also if it is going to the left and the character is <= than left bound then return; and the same on the right bound >= then return;
Something like this:

```
Transform charTransform;
float leftHorizontalBound;
float rightHorizontalBound;

void Start()
{
   charTransform = this.transform;
   leftHorizontalBound = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0,0, camera.nearClipPlane)).x;
   rightHorizontalBound= camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (1,0, camera.nearClipPlane)).x;
}

void Update()
{
   if(charTransform.position.x <= leftHorizontalBound)
   {
      charTransform.position = new vector2(leftHorizontalBound + 0.1f);
      return;
   }
   if(charTransform.position.x >= rightHorizontalBound)
   {
      charTransform.position = new vector2(rightHorizontalBound - 0.1f);
      return;
   }

   //MAKE HERE YOUR MOVEMENT BASED ON INPUT.
}
```

Dont use that code just use the idea, since i didn't test it, i just code it here.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Charecter moves through the border of the scene, in debug it says that charecter always have 0 0 0 coords, why?